# Bitfinex API limit

Tags: api, bitfinex

There is currently an API limit of 60 requests per minute on [Bitfinex](https://www.bitfinex.com/pages/api).

Question is whether this limit is related to:

- **1) single IP address**,

If so, can I have more IPs linked to one account each of which having the 60request/minute linit?

- **2) user account**,

If so, can I have more accounts with the same IP address?

- **3) single API key**

If so, can I have more keys to one account each of which having separate request limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I emailed them about this:

> The limit is measured **per IP address** and **per account**. So for one
>   account (regardless of the number of key/secret pairs) 60 requests per
>   minute can be made via our API. When you are using multiple
>   connections (IP addresses), the combined sum of all request for the
>   account in question will used to determine if you are below the
>   60/minute limit.
>
> We hope this response has sufficiently answered your questions.

Comment: How do you measure the amount of the requests? Do you make it every minute or you start a minute and calculation only when the new request arrives after a delay?

Can I for ex. make one request every second during one minute and then make 60 requests at once during the first second of the second minute?

Comment: @Roces Presumably, they do it by incrementing a counter every time a request comes in. Or am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: @NickODell sorry, updated my question. Hit enter too early.

Comment: What about WebSocket technology from Binance? Are there any rate limits?

Answer (score 1):

My finding for bitfinex rate limit is this: 1 second is divided up in milliseconds. 60 requests must span the entire second.

For example, if you have a foreach loop you'll get a rate limit error in less than 15 requests, because you are querying too fast. So add usleep (microsecond sleep in PHP) to span your requests for the entire second and or have multiple IP's assigned to your VPS or dedicated box and use this curl option.

```
  <?php
  $ips = array('1.1.1.1','1.1.1.2','1.1.1.3');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $ips[array_rand($ips)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to comment on the other answer, but my rep isn't high enough.  I wanted to point out that Nick's presumption about using the counter makes sense but doesn't answer the question, which, assuming his presumption is correct, leaves this unanswered: When is the counter reset?

I would implement it this way, and (to be safe) assume that this is how they did it: On each request, if the number of requests matching either your account or your IP (or both) in the last 60 seconds is over 60, then the request is denied.  This means that one of the "60 requests at once during the first second of the second minute" would get answered and the rest would fail.  There would be no counter, but instead a record of all requests (IP, account, timestamp) that is purged of records over a minute old as often as necessary to keep the server healthy.